# I sent it to https when I requested axios, but it will be transferred to http

Tags: amazon-web-services, https

It's my first time trying to distribute the homepage using aws, and there's a problem!
First, I checked that S3 is connected using cloudfront using route53,
ec2 also made a node balancer and asked route53 to confirm that the server is connected well.
But the problem seems to be that both of them are working well in https.
But if I send a request, an error occurs like this.
But the thing is, when I asked the client to fix the problem, I changed it from http://localhost:4000 to https://domain_name, and I keep getting this error, where is that http://localhost:4000 coming from?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/L7hkA.png

Comment: this question is impossible to answer without a link to the site and further information.

Comment: I am not sure whether or not I understood the question, but if you are using AWS SDK to connect to your resources, they are based on Access Key. The first question comes in mind is: did you generate the Access Key? is the client working correctly? Did you set correctly the permission to access the resource?